# Can't edit anything in settings editor (xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, gconf

Even with root privileges when I open **settings editor->xfce-keyboard-shortcuts**, I am forbidden to do any changes. More precisely, I cannot type anything in **`property`** field of any shortcuts.

I tried to change positions of close button by changing values in **`settings editor->xsettings->DecorationLayout`**. It resets itself after closing settings editor. and no change is reflected.

I am using xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did you try `sudo su` instead of just `sudo`

Comment: @Faizan I tried it. No improvements :(

Comment: Are you able to use xfconf-query with a command such as this: xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -n -t string -p "/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>8" -s mousepad

Comment: Did you check permissions by running: ll ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/

Comment: @jbrock all are having permission `-rw-rw-r--`

Comment: @jbrock Your command works. I did `xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -n -t string -p "/commands/default/<Super>" -s xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`. It got changed in settings, but changes were not reflected

Comment: @SeverusTux I wish I knew how to fix the Settings Editor issue. So, the command was successful, but the new settings are not reflected in Settings Editor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39021/discussion-between-jbrock-and-severus-tux).